# Query for a many to many relationship in Spring Jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to do a query in a many-to-many relationship with Spring Data Jpa if it is possible by name convention (because the query would be pretty long). This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Rental extends BaseEntity<Long> {
    private int price;
    private long clientId;
    private long gunTypeId;
}
```

And I want to find the most rented gun type.

I am using Ids for now instead of Spring annotations, because it's a uni project and I have to change to Spring relationships just after.
This was the method without Spring:

```
public GunType getMostRentedGunType() {
        log.trace("getMostRentedGunType: --- method entered");
        try {
            Map<Long, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
            this.getAllRentals().forEach(rental -> {
                count.put(rental.getGunTypeId(), count.getOrDefault(rental.getGunTypeId(), 0) + 1);
            });

            var max = count.entrySet().stream()
                    .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
                    .get()
                    .getKey();
            var result = gunTypeRepository.findById(max).orElse(null);
            log.trace("getMostRentedGunType: result={}", result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I am wondering if somebody can help do this by name convention or bu using @Query annotation.

I tried in the next way:

```
@Query(value = "select gt from guntype gt where gt.id in (select r.guntypeid from rental r group by (r.guntypeid) order by count(r) desc limit 1)", nativeQuery = true)
    GunType getMostRentedGunType();
```

but I get the error:
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2002

Comment: Can you try something like @Query("SELECT r.gunTypeId, count(r) from Rentals r group by (r.gunTypeId) ORDER BY count(r) LIMIT 1")

Comment: I have a dialect error this way. I added it in the question, if you can help me please